# How to manage multiple domains on same server

Tags: domains, apache, htaccess

I have more than one (4 to be exact) domains and only one server host with same ip. How I can run all my domains from same server. All websites are wordpress sites.

Comment: This is a server configuration issue. Whether all the sites are WordPress or not doesn't make a difference in this context ... migrating to Webmasters Stack Exchange where it will be more on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Apache on your web server then you should use Name-Based Virtual Hosting, which is explained in the [Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html).

Comment: I reluctantly gave an upvote. Your answer would be a lot better if you could give a paraphrased summary of the link and/or provide some sample configurations to demonstrate how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code in the `htaccess` file to manage my wordpresses with multiple domains all pointing to the same site (though this isn't wordpress specific).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Basically this redirects any domain that **isn't** `yourdomain.com` **to** `yourdomain.com`.

This way you avoid any crossdomain violations (with embedded fonts for example), all your sites are accessible from all domains but you only have a single root domain so far as users, bookmarks and search engines are concerned.

You may also want to read this [google webmaster blog on canonical urls](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html).

Comment: I won't downvote but this doesn't answer the question. I think what the op is referring to is multiple subdomains on a site, not multiple subdomains pointing to one subdomain. Ex. site.com, blog1.site.com, blog2.site.com, blogs.site.com, mail.site.com (webmail), admin.site.com, www.site.com (redirects to site.com), etc...

Comment: @EvanPlaice well, i don't see where you get sub domains from since the question doesn't mention them but re-reading the question you could be right it's not terribly clear.

Comment: Here's what I grok'd. 1 domain name, 1 host, multiple sites. If the host is running an Apache server that would mean adding subdomains using Virtual Hosts in httpd.conf. In some other type of hosting framework (ex Google App Engine) it would probably mean adding sub-domain handles to the config/router.

Comment: @EvanPlaice you could well be right I took the plural websites and sites to be bad English.

Comment: He says "All websites are Wordpress sites" which implies they are set up as separate sites, not just several domains pointing to the same site. I removed the redirect tags since the question doesn't appear to be about that.